# Encrypt files using openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, openssl

I have seen solutions for encrypting files using `openssl_encrypt` from the command line, like so:

```
file_put_contents ('./file.encrypted',openssl_encrypt ($source, $method, $pass, true, $iv));

$exec = "openssl enc -".$method." -d -in file.encrypted -nosalt -nopad -K ".strtohex($pass)." -iv ".strtohex($iv);
```

Or, using `openssl_encrypt` to encrypt strings, like this:

```
$string = 'It works ? Or not it works ?';
$pass = '1234';
$method = 'aes128';
file_put_contents ('./file.encrypted', openssl_encrypt ($string, $method, $pass));
```

But not something for encrypting the the files directly from the code. Why is that ?

What if I want to encrypt 2-10mb files from the code instead of opening separate processes for each file like what happens using the command line ?

I'm looking for code example that will do that for me, something like:

```
$myfile = 'files/myfile.doc';
$pass = '1234';
$method = 'aes128';
file_put_contents ('./file.encrypted', openssl_encrypt ($myfile, $method, $pass));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you can't read a file into a variable using file_get_contents(), encrypt it using openssl_public_encrypt() and then save it out to disk using fopen() fwrite() and fclose(), but there's presumably a limit on what size of file you can load into memory with this approach.

There may also be a performance overhead doing the file encryption in-script, but you should be able to test this easily enough.

Comment: thanks, i ended up using the first block of code. it seems to be fine as far as performance