# PHP: Encrypt files using openssl_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

Is there a way to encrypt the whole file(code) using `openssl_encrypt`. I found a related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223351/encrypt-files-using-openssl-encrypt), but don't know how to convert it.

I just need a simple code for me to get started..

This is the code I'm trying to convert.

```
<?php
$key = 'bRuD5WYw5wd0rdHR9yLlM6wt2vteuiniQBqE70nAuhU=';

function my_encrypt($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}

function my_decrypt($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
}

$password_plain = 'abc123';
echo $password_plain . "<br>";

$password_encrypted = my_encrypt($password_plain, $key);
echo $password_encrypted . "<br>";

$password_decrypted = my_decrypt($password_encrypted, $key);
echo $password_decrypted . "<br>";
```

Hope you help you.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean the "whole file(code)"?

Comment: @Joseph_J its like file_get_contents, all the codes inside will be encrypted, not sure if thats possible.

Comment: The use of :: as a delimiter for the $iv, gives an attacker a clear view of your used $iv. You better try another way (e.g. put it in specific place, within the cipher text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your encrypt and decrypt functions work properly.

You code flow should look something like this:

```
$code = file_get_contents('path/to/code.php'); //Get the code to be encypted.
$encrypted_code = my_encrypt($code, $key); //Encrypt the code.
echo 'Encrypted Code <br><br>';
echo $encrypted_code;

file_put_contents('path/to/save/encrypted_code.php', $encrypted_code); //Save the ecnypted code somewhere.

$encrypted_code = file_get_contents('path/to/save/encrypted_code.php'); //Get the encrypted code.
$decrypted_code = my_decrypt($encrypted_code, $key);//Decrypt the encrypted code.
echo 'Decrypted Code <br><br>';
echo $decrypted_code;

file_put_contents('path/to/save/code.php', $decrypted_code); //Save the decrypted code somewhere.
```

This is just a very basic example.

There are also additional parameters for the `file_put_contents()` that you should read about.

Make sure that any file that you write to has the proper write permissions or the file will not be able to be able to be saved.  The `chmod()` function can be used to manipulate your folder/file permissions.

A good encryption library that I recommend is [Libsodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/01-quick-start.md#which-tool).  It is now available in PHP >=7.2 It is a powerful encryption library.  You should check it out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good I'm glad it helped!  Good luck with the rest of your project.  ~Cheers!

Comment: I have been looking for a simple way to explain openssl to some students and this hits the mark. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Woody, I would make sure that you are using the correct encryption algorithms for each function with no typos.  Second I would research openssl for error handling suggestions and put you code in a try/catch block.  You can use the openssl_error_string() to catch the last error that the openssl library created when it last run.   If you can't readily figure it out I would open a new question and post your code.

Comment: Thans for the pointers @Joseph_J! Spending a few days learning about Libsodium, really liking.